# Interpreting double digit numbers

Tags: python, digits

So, I'm having a bit of trouble with this piece of code.

```
if s.get("home") < s.get("away"):
        scoringplays = scoringplays + s.get("away") + "-" + s.get("home") + " " + game.get("away_team_name")
    elif s.get("home") > s.get("away"):
        scoringplays = scoringplays + s.get("home") + "-" + s.get("away") + " " + game.get("home_team_name")
    else:
        scoringplays = scoringplays + s.get("home") + "-" + s.get("away") + " Tied"
```

It pulls the score of a baseball game from MLB and posts it to reddit like so:

4-3 Winning Team Name

However, I've noticed if one of the scores is in double digits, the code seems to only read the first digit, so a score of 10-2 would display like so:

2-10 Losing Team Name

I've searched around a bit, and perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms, but I can't seem to find an answer in here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. It's python. Thanks for being so cordial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're comparing strings:

```
>>> "10" < "2"
True
```

Compare their integer version:

```
if int(s.get("home")) < int(s.get("away"))
```

If the key is missing from the dict then `dict.get` returns `None` by default. You can also pass your own default value.

```
home_score = int(s.get("home", 0))  # or choose some other default value
away_score = int(s.get("away", 0))

if home_score < away_score:
     #do something
```

Demo:

```
>>> int("10") < int("2")
False
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when I try that: TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Comment: @user2536657 this means either `s.get("home")` or `s.get("away")` is returning `None`. You can also use a default value : `s.get("home", 0)`, here 0 will be returned if the key "home" is not found.